# How to get jspm 17 build to behave the same way as jspm 16 bundle-sfx

Tags: bundle, systemjs, jspm, jspm-server

I have this npm script

```
jspm build src/cupidAnalytics.ts dist/cupidAnalytics.js --minify --skip-source-maps
```

using

```
"dependencies": {
    "jspm": "^0.17.0-beta.41" 
}
```

but the output is producing

```
TypeError: ramda_1.compose is not a function
```

Ultimately I am trying to get build to work similar to bundle-sfx where

```
<script>
    SystemJS.import('test.js');
</script>
```

Is not required

Comment: They should behave the same way. That error must come from an unmet dependency, outdated node version, outdated system.js loader, outdated builder, etc. Please provide more context to your error to see if it sheds some light upon its root cause

Comment: @amenadiel thanks for the response. I'm using
node v7.8.0
"jspm": "^0.17.0-beta.41"
"es6-module-loader": "npm:es6-module-loader@^0.17.11"

From the jspm release docs it says 0.17.0-beta.41 uses
SystemJS 0.20.10 and SystemJS Builder 0.16.4.